# ClickableSpan onClick not working android java

Tags: java, android

I am developing an `android` SMS application using `java` and I want to check if the received message contains a phone number. If yes, I want to make the phone number bold and underlined and when user clicks on it, I want to open a popup for options like Call, Add To Contacts etc. I have done everything except for the part where I want to show the popup when user clicks on the phone number. I tried using `ClickableSpan` but the `onClick` method never triggers. Here is what I have done so far:

```
String finalMsg;
        String ifNumberExists = Util.extractNumber(message.getMessageBody());
        String boldNum = "<b><u>" + ifNumberExists + "</u></b>";

        if (message.getMessageBody().contains(ifNumberExists)) {
            finalMsg = message.getMessageBody().replace(ifNumberExists, boldNum);
        } else {
            finalMsg = message.getMessageBody();
        }

        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(boldNum);
        spannableString.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(@NonNull View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(viewMessageThreadActivity, "Text: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, 0, boldNum.length() - 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        TextView messageBodyLabel = rowView.findViewById(R.id.message_body_label);
        messageBodyLabel.setText(Html.fromHtml(finalMsg));
        messageBodyLabel.setClickable(true);
        messageBodyLabel.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating `spannableString`, but enver uses that, `TextView` have set `Html.fromHtml(finalMsg)` as a content. set this `spannableString` as text to get desired result (and `onClick` working)

```
messageBodyLabel.setText(spannableString.toString());
```

Comment: if I does this then I only see bold and underlined phone number but I want to display the whole message alongwith the phone number. By the way, I did this too but still onClick didn't work.

Comment: remove `messageBodyLabel.setClickable(true);`, this may make whole `TextView` clickable, which swallows touch event on particular area, e.g. `spannableString` part with `onClick`

Comment: already tried this but not working.

Comment: the initial problem was caused by not setting `spannableString` with `onClick` to your `TextView`. but all other parts looks properly, maybe there is some wrong attribute set for `TextView` in XML... sadly I don't have a other clue...